# regex with letters and number combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I am trying to create a regex for a format:

TNP-XXXXX

Only the letters TNP and - are allowed and the XXXXX are numbers, it can only accept up to 5 numbers.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if !(/TNP-[\d]{5,}$/.match(tc_number))
   raise "Is not in the correct format, It should be TNP-XXXXX"
end
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: For upto 5 use `\d{1,5}`. The square braces are not needed. Whereas `\d{5,}` means 5 or more.

Comment: @AdrianHHH,  don't forget that `\d{1,5}` matches `"9999999999999"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Agreed, but the question uses that segment of a RegEx with other things before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues with your regex.

1. It's not anchored at the start, so `ABC TNP-12345` will match.
2. `[\d]{5,}` says to match *at least* 5 digits. So `TNP-123` will not match.

Also the `[]` is unnecessary. `[]` is for building arbitrary character classes. `\d` is already a [character class](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Character+Classes) equivalent to `[0-9]` and does not need to be put inside a character class.

You instead want `/^TNP-\d{1,5}$/` to indicate a string starting with `TNP-` and 1 to 5 digits.

```
tests = ["ABC TNP-12345", "TNP-12345", "TNP-123", "TNP-", "TNP-ABC", "ABC-12345", "TNC-123456"]
tests.each do |test|
  puts "#{test} - #{/^TNP-[\d]{1,5}$/.match?(test)}"
end
```

```
ABC TNP-12345 - false
TNP-12345 - true
TNP-123 - true
TNP- - false
TNP-ABC - false
ABC-12345 - false
TNC-123456 - false
```

Comment: Thank you this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Only the letters TNP and - are allowed and the XXXXX are numbers, it can only accept up to 5 numbers. ..."*

Use `{1,5}` to match the preceding element, *1* to *5* times.

Additionally, use the `\b` word-boundary syntax to avoid matching sub-sequences.

```
\bTNP-\d{1,5}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should anchor the Regexp to start and end of the Line/String (use `\A\z` or `^$` depending on what you need)
- You do not need `[]` because it is for specifying a group of characters and `\d` is already a group
- You should use `match?` instead of `match` if you do not need the captures (more performant)

You can test your Regexp on a site like rubular: https://rubular.com/r/U4vUVb68TiIzRp

In Short:

```rb
RE_FORMAT = /^TNP-\d{5}$/
if !(RE_FORMAT.match?(tc_number))
   raise "Is not in the correct format, It should be TNP-XXXXX"
end
```

Comment: oh, copied from the wrong experiment.